# Open service mesh: wait until adding a namespace is complete

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, sidecar, helmfile, open-service-mesh

I am installing Open Service Mesh (OSM) and my app via `helmfile` .  I control the order of installation by using multiple `helmfile`s, and I proceed like so.

1. I install osm
2. I install my app `namespace`, along with the OSM annotations so that OSM knows to inject a sidecar into all entities joining the namespace (see below)
3. I wait for OSM to recognise the namespace (how to do this elegantly is my question).
4. I install the app in my `namespace`.

My issue is that OSM seems to take a few seconds to recognize the new namespace.  If I don't  insert a pause, then I end up with some pods that do not seem to have the sidecar injected into them. Is there some service/job in OSM that I can watch so that I know when the namespace registration is complete?  I could not find this in the documentation.

---

Code:

My main `helmfile` is as follows:

```
helmfiles:
- apps/00-service-mesh/helmfile.yaml
- apps/10-namespace/helmfile.yaml
- apps/20-database/helmfile.yaml
```

**Step 1) Service Mesh:**

```
repositories:
- name: osm
  url: https://openservicemesh.github.io/osm
 
releases:
- name: osm
  namespace: osm-system
  chart: osm/osm
  version: '1.2.4'
  values:
  - ./values/osm.yaml
```

with values:

```
osm:
  enablePermissiveTrafficPolicy: true
  deployPrometheus: true
  deployGrafana: true
  osmNamespace: osm-system

contour:
  enabled: true
  configInline.tls:
    envoy-client-certificate:
      name: osm-contour-envoy-client-cert  
      namespace: osm-system
```

**Step 2 and 3) Namespace & Sleep**

I create a custom chart with the namespace defined with the OSM annotations:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: myNamespace
  labels:
    "openservicemesh.io/monitored-by": "osm"
  annotations:
    'openservicemesh.io/sidecar-injection': 'enabled'
    "openservicemesh.io/metrics": "enabled"
```

While this works fine when I add the namespace with the `kubectl` command, it seems to "go too quick" when scripting with `helmfile`.

To workaround for now, I have a inelegant pause.  *This is what I want to replace with something more reliable*

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: sleep-job
  namespace: myNamespace
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: node-app-job
        image: alpine
        command: ["sleep", "20"]
      restartPolicy: Never
```

My helmcart is then:

```
releases:
- name: app-namespace
  chart: ./app-namespace
  hooks:
  - events: ["postsync"]
    showlogs: true
    command: "kubectl"
    args: ["wait", "--for=condition=complete", "job/sleep-job", "-n", "myNamespace"]
```

With the pause this works okay.  If I remove the pause it seems that some pods (step 4) don't have the sidecar and are unreachable. How do I replace the pause with something more relibale.

Comment: Do Helmfile [hooks](https://helmfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#hooks) block further progress in a way that will give the controller time to react?

Comment: @DavidMaze, to be honest I am quite new to it.  My understanding is that each file in the `helmfiles` section is treated in alphabetical order, and so `apps/10-namespace/helmfile.yaml` will complete before `apps/20-database/helmfile.yaml` starts.  The idea was to make the `10-namespace` section take a bit longer. 

Maybe I overcomplicate it a little.  Maybe I just need to create an `init` container that waits for `osm namespace list` to return the appropriate result.  I will play around a bit.